# SSRS - different permissions for the same reports

Tags: reporting-services, permissions

I have 3 brands, and each brand has it's own mysql database.

In general each database has the same schema, unless they're out of sync due to different release dates.

I have a Microsoft database with each mysql db as a linked database.
Also, I have different schema in the Microsoft database for each product, with views using openquery to get the data from the linked mysql databases.

Lastly, there is a 4th schema which is a union of the views from the different product schemas. All reports are based off this 4th schema, so they include data from all 3 brands.

Now, we need to segment by brand. Reports should be the same, but some people should only have permission to see specific brands, some should see all brands, etc.

What is the best way to do this, so I still only have to maintain one version of each report?

I thought of linked reports in different folders, but how do I build in the permission by brand?

Answer (score 0):

You could try leveraging the built-in "UserId" variable (=User!UserID) to either integrate with an existing security schema, or build your own, and perform data filtering accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @kyzen. I didn't know about this option. I see there's no built in variable for the user's Window's group. So it must be at the level of the user, and not at the group level. Correct?

Comment: Correct, which is quite inconvenient.  I've seen a few solutions to this - bridge/mapping tables, dumping your AD hierarchy into a database, switching to forms-based authentication and sourcing credentials elsewhere, etc.  Long story short, what you're trying to do is entirely possible... it's just not going to be fun.

Comment: Oy. Okay, thank you. I'll leave as unresolved, in case someone has another suggestion.